# Stuck with apt --fix-broken install (libc6:amd64 package post-installation)

Tags: ubuntu, package, apt, ubuntu-20.04

My system runs inside WSL, I upgrade it at least every few days.
I stuck with one package installation, and looking for a way to solve this:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbind9-161 libdns-export1107 libdns1107 libdns1109 libirs161 libisc-export1104 libisc1104 libisc1105 libisccc161
  libisccfg163 liblwres161 liboauth0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 882 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/633 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu6) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Nothing to restart.
sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and this procedure from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1871240) fixed it:

> Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6\:amd64.postinst`
>
> and comment out the line
>
> `# set -e`
>
> so $ `apt-get -f install` can continue.

Comment: Thank you, it helped, finally I can transfer from testing to 20.04LTS

Comment: @AdamMierzwiak Be careful, this merely disables "stop on errors" in that post-install script; Ubuntu fossal doesn't officially work in WSL1, so it's probably better to upgrade to WSL2 before. This might not be the only problem.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, currently system is blocked on older Win10 than that supporting WSL2 by domain administrator

Comment: If you cannot spot it, it is the second line!

Comment: You have saved me!

Comment: Thank you. I am having to switch to WSL after my cygwin installation ballsed up, figured may as well make the switch now but ran into this issue quickly. Thank you for a simple and accurate solution.

Comment: This solution I used also to transform from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 testing. Same problem appears

Comment: I faced with the problem with kali

Comment: Next time you cant find what youre looking for, use nano, Ctrl + W and type the keyword and enter. It will move the cursor where that keyword is. If it's not that one, press Ctrl + W again and just press enter (memorises your last input). I use this alot and it helps

Comment: I have been trying to fix this for hours now, you just saved me. BTW after that I ran apt update and dist upgrade to wrap things up.

Comment: this file not exist in my ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 16):

You can use this sequence of commands (up to 3) to force a re-download of the partial files of the offending packages. Remaining steps are done to merge the new files with the old one, to avoid warnings and issues on non-offending packages that do not get downloaded in this attempt.

1. `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info_old`
2. `sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info`
3. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install`
4. `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/* /var/lib/dpkg/info_old`
5. `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info`
6. `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info_old /var/lib/dpkg/info`

Comment: ```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file
or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
```

Comment: What is the aim of steps 4 to 6? Seems like not visible effect from system standpoint or I miss something ?

Comment: THanks @OdTu  you saved my day .... I was having trouble installing libmysqlclient-dev and only this solution worked

Comment: In my case it did not solved the issue, but I see that some other people issues were covered. Thank you

Comment: Steps 4-6 literally do nothing. Steps 1-3 didn't help me.

Comment: Solved an issue with borked docker configuration. Tx.

Comment: In my situation, I used `dpkg --configure -a` instead of `apt update && apt -f install` and finally successfully fix it.

Comment: This basically destroyed my shell, I had to refit the entire system to gain access again! Not a solution. `-bash: /usr/bin/apt: cannot execute: required file not found`

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem when upgrading Kali Linux inside WSL. I used these sequence of commands to fix the issue

1. cd /tmp
2. apt -y download libcrypt1
3. dpkg-deb -x libcrypt1_1%3a4.4.27-1.1_amd64.deb  .
4. cp -av lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
5. apt -y --fix-broken install

Comment: I ran into this upgrading debian 10 to debian 12. This fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. For wine, I had to install libc6:i386, into an existing docker image.

I checked `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:i386.postinst` and saw that there is a call to `ischroot`. Its [source code](https://github.com/juaristi/debianutils/blob/master/ischroot.c) (first search result though) didn't show me anything I could fake, but I was able to fake the whole tool by simply replacing it.

The result was the following line (note the `mv` and `cp` commands)

```
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
 && apt-get update \
 && mv -v /usr/bin/ischroot /usr/bin/ischroot.disabled \
 && cp -v /usr/bin/true /usr/bin/ischroot \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        wine32 \
 && mv -v /usr/bin/ischroot.disabled /usr/bin/ischroot \
 && apt-get clean
```

Comment: Great hint! What is your usecase with wine?

Comment: right now it's only an experimental platform. I hate polluting my host system with packages I install only once for a little test. I have multiple Linux GUI applications packed into docker images which run very nicely and safe, for example a sandboxed firefox environment or spotify

Answer (score 0):

set -x showed that in my case /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:amd64.postinst hangs on

- [ yes = yes ]
- telinit u

doesn't match well with wsl

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).